# Is Mono for OS X any good for a professional .NET developer?

Tags: .net, macos, mono

As a professional .net developer (at least this is how I earn my money) I wonder if Mono for the Mac is worth a closer look.
I already tried Mono 3 years ago when I first got my iMac but the installation was impossible to master and after half a day I just gave up.
I also got help from a Unix professional but we both were unable to get Mono running on my Mac.

Like I said that was some years ago. How is the state of Mono for OS X today? Installation still painful? How about compatibility to .NET Framework 2.0?

Comment: Do you mean as a development environment or to be able to say your application supports MacOSX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Today Mono is quite mature in terms of performance and stability. The current version, Mono 2.4, has a full implementation of .NET 2.0 including ASP.NET. This also supports C# 3.0 and almost all APIs of .NET 3.5, and yes, it supports ASP.NET MVC as well.
My experience with my Mac and Mono is very positive, including for development environment. I prefer to use Textmate + Compiler but there is a good IDE out there: MonoDevelop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I agree that Mono as a platform for OSX development has matured to a usable level for professional development. Unfortunately, I can't say the same for MonoDevelop yet. Even the website says that MonoDevelop for OSX is still at preview level and has many bugs and issues. Hopefully it will mature to a professional level soon.
As an aside, there are two other IDEs that can be used for .NET development on OSX - X-Develop (http://www.omnicore.com/en/) and Eclipse (http://vanirsystems.com/danielsblog/2008/01/02/mac-os-x-mono-eclipse-and-virtuoso/)

Comment: Agreed, that's why I'm using Textmate. But the MonoDevelop for Linux  is really nice and I'm sure that MonoDevelop for Mac will reach the same quality.

Comment: Yes, those nerds (more than professional) are still using Emacs and GCC.

Comment: +1, but I prefer using Visual Studio inside of a VM. Resharper is just too good not to.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy to set it up. It's much more mature than it was 3 years ago but you should still consider libraries that have problems with Mono. I mean, you should test apps rather than blindly assuming its compatible with Mono.

From a developer perspective, MonoDevelop hardly competes even with a half of Visual Studio Express.

Comment: Not to mention that MonoDevelop on OS X seems to vary in terms of stability as time goes by.

Answer (score 1):

If you are curious whether your application would run on Mono, there's an application called [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) that analyzes your code and tells you where you might have a problem.